# Question can I rest Samsung Galaxy s9+ knox Counter

Tags: rest, samsung-knox

I have Samsung Galaxy s9+ and I want to root it but I have problem that if I rooted my device the Knox counter

If Root works for a device, the counter will recognize the process of modification. If this is detected, can I reset a Knox  counter?
And recover device warranty after root

Answer (score 0):

I had difficulty understanding your English so, I will try to answer in parts

> Will Knox recognize the root process?

Most likely. There are ways to prevent detection, but are device specific, and build specific. ChainFire, sideloading, auto-roots and many other common, generic rooting procedures will be detected.

> If the root is detected, can it be reset?

No. Samsung uses specific hardware, that marks itself as "unsafe", thus never recovering from the mark.

> Can I recover the warranty?

No. But, depending on what you use the warranty for, the technician is likely to not even bother checking. Its about luck mostly, and what you are warranting it for.